# propagating text direction for entire page

Tags: css, html

While doing localization, in some RTL language, the text is not in the right direction. This requires me to do `dir=auto` on those elements so the text will behave normally.

However, this is required for each element, making the page riddled with these tags.

Is there a way to make the entire page dir autoable (preferably without javascript? (I could do something like `$("div,span,input").attr("dir","auto")` but is that really required?)

Comment: Shouldn't it work by just adding the `dir` attribute to the `html` tag? E.g. according to this: http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-dir

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work... :(